# How to remove ribbon buttons from a content type in Sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

Is it possible to remove the ribbon buttons from a content type in Sharepoint online using CSOM? If it is possible, how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123073/hide-list-content-type-via-csom

Comment: @Anuja I want to remove the ribbon buttons and context menus associated with the content type, I think above question-related to hiding the content 
type for a list.